# Suggest best reporting tool with selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, reporting

I have done with my selenium webdriver script.now,I have tried `TestNG` and `XSLT` but still manager is not satisfied with output of generated reports. please suggest me best reporting tools for selenium.

Comment: Have a look at extent report, which coughs up dashboard, pie-chart, summaries and other bells and whistles by default... http://extentreports.com/. One downside, at least in earlier version, is your selenium code will contain some amount of reporting code also. Maybe this has been reduced. Else you can create your own custom reports using the ITestListener for testng or testWatcher for junit

Comment: MUST LOOK at Serenity

Answer (score 3):

I use following reports while working with TestNG and Selenium.

**ReportNG**: This is similar to TestNG report however looks far better than TestNG. 
http://reportng.uncommons.org/

**Maven SureFire Report**: if you are using maven project you can have maven surefire plugin and generate a report, it's also far better than that of TestNG.

http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/

**ExtentReport**: this is my favorite. It's bit tricky to configure but worth it. It has **extentx** server as well which stores historical data.

http://extentreports.com/

http://extentreports.com/docs/extentx/

Comment: Note: ReportNG is no longer maintained. May I also suggest Allure Report?

Answer (score 2):

Selenium itself does not provide any reporting features. Reporting is provided by the platform you are using to run tests. As you mentioned yourself, tools like TestNG, jUnit or even Cucumber. Perhaps there are some extensions to these testing frameworks that can provide better results.

What exactly your boss is unhappy with? Perhaps you can tune some settings to improve the current result?